# Fetching records from db and assign it to an array to be used for mail reporting in Linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am creating a report that will be run through UNIX shell script. One query needs to run on DB side and the fetched variable then those variables need to use in mail subject and body.

```
results=($(mysql --user ${DB_USER} -p${DB_PWD} ${DB_NAME} -Bse "select company_name,City,bill_amount from myTable;"))
```

Say result has two rows :

```
Company Name=" Google India", ,City='Mumbai' bill_amount='2500'
Company Name=" fasttrack Pvt Ltd", ,City='Mumbai' bill_amount='7500'
```

Now in do while loop I want these variables to be concated and shown Like this :

```
msg[0]='Company $company_name from $city has amount $bill_amount to be paid'
```

And then this `msg` to be sent through mail function.

Please suggest how to create this msg in Linux shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me...

```
while company_name city bill_amount
do
        echo "Company $company_name from $city has amount $bill_amount to be paid"
#use mail function to send each row
done < <(echo "SELECT company_name,city,bill_amount FROM dbname.tablename" | mysql -N -uuser -ppassword)
```

Comment: Hi Arjun, 
Thanks for reply , Don't know where the issue, But it is giving syntax error:

syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./test.sh: line 6: `                    done < <(echo "select company_name,

Comment: There were some formatting issues, I fixed that and now the loop is working but it hangs showing null :

[~/scripts/test]# Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Comment: Hi Arpit, Did u fix the issue?

Comment: HI Arjun, Thanks for help.  
But not yet even I changed the bash but it is still showing error, Now I am working on some workaround.